# Configure web service with both a Username Token and an x509 certificate using SVCConfigEditor

Tags: wcf, service, web, client

For a WCF web service client, is it possible to configure a web service with both a Username Token and an x509 certificate using SVCConfigEditor?

Is the following wsdl helpful in this interop scenario with an IBM Websphere web service?
Thank you, 
Greg

```
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="policy0" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<wsp:ExactlyOne>
  <wsp:All>
    <sp:AsymmetricBinding xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
      <wsp:Policy>
        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
          <wsp:All>
            <sp:InitiatorToken>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <wsp:ExactlyOne>
                  <wsp:All>
                    <sp:X509Token>
                      <wsp:Policy>
                        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
                          <wsp:All>
                            <sp:WssX509V3Token11 />
                          </wsp:All>
                        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
                      </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:X509Token>
                  </wsp:All>
                </wsp:ExactlyOne>
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:InitiatorToken>
            <sp:RecipientToken>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <wsp:ExactlyOne>
                  <wsp:All>
                    <sp:X509Token>
                      <wsp:Policy>
                        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
                          <wsp:All>
                            <sp:WssX509V3Token11 />
                          </wsp:All>
                        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
                      </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:X509Token>
                  </wsp:All>
                </wsp:ExactlyOne>
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:RecipientToken>
            <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <wsp:ExactlyOne>
                  <wsp:All>
                    <sp:TripleDesRsa15 />
                  </wsp:All>
                </wsp:ExactlyOne>
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
          </wsp:All>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
      </wsp:Policy>
    </sp:AsymmetricBinding>
    <sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
      <sp:Body />
    </sp:SignedParts>
    <sp:EncryptedParts xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
      <sp:Body />
    </sp:EncryptedParts>
  </wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
```

http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702
    
          
      Implements WS Security Policy 1.2 - UsernameToken 1.0 support

Answer (score 0):

Not possibnle with plain svcutil, you need [custom code](http://leastprivilege.com/2008/01/31/username-supportingtoken-in-wcf/). However you could create a binding (via code) with username supporting token and then use svcutil to define this binding.

Comment: Thank you for ideas @yaron. How (what svcutil command line options would I use) to define this binding?

Comment: see here in section "custom implementation" how to build the binding and in the following section how to define it in xml. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/243357/WCF-Custom-Binding instead of xml you could use svcutil, the key would be file-->Open-->Executable... where you choose the dll of your binding. Then it will be available normally like any other binding (you may need to dismiss or approve some message boxes)

Comment: That custom code example uses a wcf server..i'll see how this works with the IBM Websphere server  http://12.23.28.113:9047/MHService?wsdl on the other side. Not sure if this interop situation introduces any additional surprises.

Comment: i am looking at the custom implementation section of that article. studying. have some ambiguous namespaces when implementing- so need to understand what it what. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think its pretty obvious by now that SVCConfigEditor is not the tool. This was a suggestion that does not take into consideration custom binding, which it doesn't seem to be able to accommodate.  Thank you to @Yaron for ideas even though I have not successfully implemented a solution yet.

**although I would appreciate clarification @Yaron or a link to how to achieve the following, "instead of xml you could use svcutil, the key would be file-->Open-->Executable... where you choose the dll of your binding. Then it will be available normally like any other binding (you may need to dismiss or approve some message boxes)"****